# For Loop and Parallel Arrays : Undeclared Identifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I just started learning about arrays and I have a tenuous grasp on them.
Tried making this program in a lab today and keep getting an **error** that **numJarsSold, typesOfSalsa, and totalJarsSold are undeclared identifiers** in **MyFunctions.cpp**. I've found online already that people have had the same project and seen their code and I've written my own to run just in main but somehow running it separated I've managed to break it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Main.cpp

```
#include "MyFunctions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
const int SIZE = 5;

string typesOfSalsa[SIZE] = { "Mild", "Medium", "Sweet", "Hot", "Zesty" };
int numJarsSold[SIZE]; // Holds Number of Jars of Salsa sold for each type

int totalJarsSold = getJarSalesData(typesOfSalsa, numJarsSold);

displayReport(typesOfSalsa, numJarsSold, totalJarsSold);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

MyFunctions.cpp

```
#include "MyFunctions.h"
using namespace std;


int getJarSalesData(string typesOfSalsa[], int numJarsSold[])
{
    int totalJarsSold = 0;

    for (int type = 0; type < SIZE; type++)
    {
        cout << "Jars sold last month of " << typesOfSalsa[type] << ": ";
        cin >> numJarsSold[type];


        while (numJarsSold[type] < 0)
        {
            cout << "Jars sold must be 0 or more. Please re-enter: ";
            cin >> numJarsSold[type];
        }
        // Adds the number of jars sold to the total
        totalJarsSold += numJarsSold[type];
    }
    return totalJarsSold;
}

int posOfLargest(int array[])
{
    int indexOfLargest = 0;

    for (int pos = 1; pos < SIZE; pos++)
    {
        if (array[pos] > array[indexOfLargest])
            indexOfLargest = pos;
    }
    return indexOfLargest;
}

 int posOfSmallest(int array[])
{
    int indexOfSmallest = 0;
    for (int pos = 1; pos < SIZE; pos++)
    {
        if (array[pos] < array[indexOfSmallest])
            indexOfSmallest = pos;
    }
    return indexOfSmallest;
}

void displayReport(string[], int[], int)
{
    int hiSalesProduct = posOfLargest(numJarsSold);
    int loSalesProduct = posOfSmallest(numJarsSold);

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "     Salsa Sales Report \n\n";
    cout << "Name              Jars Sold \n";
    cout << "____________________________\n";
    cout << typesOfSalsa[0] << "                  " << numJarsSold[0] << "\n";
    cout << typesOfSalsa[1] << "                " << numJarsSold[1] << "\n";
    cout << typesOfSalsa[2] << "                 " << numJarsSold[2] << "\n";
    cout << typesOfSalsa[3] << "                   " << numJarsSold[3] << "\n";
    cout << typesOfSalsa[4] << "                 " << numJarsSold[4] << "\n";

    for (int type = 0; type < SIZE; type++)
    {
        cout << left << setw(25) << typesOfSalsa[type] << setw(10) << numJarsSold[type] << endl;
        cout << "\nTotal Sales: " << totalJarsSold << endl;
        cout << "High Seller: " << typesOfSalsa[hiSalesProduct] << endl;
        cout << "Low Seller: " << typesOfSalsa[loSalesProduct] << endl;
    }

}
```

MyFunctions.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int getJarSalesData(string[], int[]);
int posOfLargest(int[]);
int posOfSmallest(int[]);
void displayReport(string[], int[], int);
```

Comment: You didn't name the parameters in the `displayReport` function.  Unrelated:  You have two `SIZE` constants, one in the header and one in `main`.

Comment: I should have named the parameters in the `displayReport` function in the header file? @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: Naming the parameters in a header file declaration is optional and doesn't do anything technically (but it helps auto-document the function, if the names are good).  Naming the parameters in a source file definition is required to actually use those parameters, since that's the declaration of the thing which has that name in that scope (which might have the same name, a different name, or no name at all in the function that called it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In MyFunctions.cpp file the function := void displayReport(string[], int[], int) you didn't declared any variable name 
it should be like 
void displayReport(string typesOfSalsa[], int numJarsSold[], int totalJarsSold)
{
    // copy the code 
}
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks for the help. Defining the `void` variables fixed it.